# Strange behaviour when compiling auctex from MELPA in Emacs (w32 version) in Cygwin

Tags: emacs, auctex

I tried to compile the auctex from Emacs MELPA. The version is: 11.88.4

When I first open a .tex file, compile AUCTEX, and change to "TeX-latex-mode", Emacs will work properly, the menu bar also change to latex state.

However, when I close Emacs, restart Emacs again and open a .tex file, Emacs will give:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Autoloading failed to define function TeX-latex-mode")
```

And auctex will not work...

It seems the problem is in autoloading certain state when initialize the auctex for a tex file.

Any help?

Comment: This function is located in `latex.el`.  Does `locate-library latex` find it?

Comment: That is the problem. After I compiling auctex, the command gives the right location, '~/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.88.4/latex.elc.' But once I close and reopen Emacs again, it gives the wrong location -- the folder where I defined my own lisp. What should I do?

Comment: Sounds like a `load-path` problem.  Do you set that in your init file?  Or perhaps some initialisation that needs to be delayed to after the package is loaded... What is your emacs version?

Comment: 24.5.  I have someting like `(add-to-list 'load-path' "~/.emacs.d/x_lisp/")`, but that should not affect the auctex, shouldn it?

Comment: Do you have other packages loaded and working?

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved! My mistake.

I modularised my `init.el` and separated the LaTeX settings to `latex.el`, which conflict with the `latex.el` in auctex.

I renamed the file to `latex_settings` and everyting works fine. (A small warning that no docstring for 'tex-start-shell', but that's fine.)